# h264 mp4 index to front command line

Tags: flash, indexing, h.264, mp4

Is there any command line tools to move an h264/mp4 index to the beginning so that flash will start playing the file quicker over the net?  I am aware of the tool QTIndexSwapper however it is not command line.

Alternatively is there an ffmpeg command to place the index at the front during an encoding?

Thanks.

Comment: Video needs to be encoded with the metadata in the header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post processing in ffmpeg to move 'moov atom' in MP4 files (qt-faststart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061798/post-processing-in-ffmpeg-to-move-moov-atom-in-mp4-files-qt-faststart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enough poking around I managed to find a python script called qt-faststart that does it.  So far so good.  [qt-faststart](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart)

Answer (score 8):

As [answered](https://superuser.com/questions/851316/swapping-index-of-an-mp4-file-with-ffmpeg) a few years later;

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```