# Post processing in ffmpeg to move 'moov atom' in MP4 files (qt-faststart)

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing, mp4, video-conversion

Is it possible to run ffmpeg from the command line which will either place the 'moov atom' metadata in the beginning of the MP4 file or run the qt-faststart as a post processing operation in ffmpeg so the generated file is stream-able through the internet?

I can of course run it as a separate command, but would prefer it to be something

- as an option within ffmpeg, or
- as part of a post conversion, command line option when converting the video files via ffmpeg

---

Edit 1

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#mov

> MOV / MP4 muxer
>
> The muxer options are:
>
> ‘-moov_size bytes’
>
> ```
> Reserves space for the moov atom at the beginning of the file instead of 
> placing the moov atom at the end. If the space reserved is insufficient, 
> muxing will fail.
> ```

Comment: Yes, It is possible to move the moov atom at beginning of the  file refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44282151/6180077

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ended up setting up and running qt-faststart after ffmpeg conversion process.

Comment: This i more aptly a comment rather an answer. @stharward response qualifies more as an answer.

Answer (score 74):

Seems like faststart support has been included in ffmpeg. [FFmpeg Formats Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#MOV_002fMP4_002fISMV):

> **`-movflags faststart`**
>
> Run a second pass moving the moov atom on top of the file. This
>   operation can take a while, and will not work in various situations
>   such as fragmented output, thus it is not enabled by default.

Comment: This worked for me. It does a second pass and then the moov atom is moved to beginning. Cheers!

Comment: This worked for me only when I had the `-codec:v libx264` arguments. To support this, I had to configure ffmpeg with the `--enable-gpl --enable-libx264` options.

Comment: Any idea in which version this was added?

Comment: android's video element can start playing video via http streaming even if the moov atom is at the end. how is that possible ?

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal It probably uses the HTTP Range header to request bytes from the end of the file. The web server must support it. Same mechanism as download resuming.

Comment: command:

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -movflags faststart output.mp4

Answer (score 3):

ffmpeg has an option for [smooth streaming](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Example)

```
-movflags isml+frag_keyframe
```

and it's also useful for avoiding corrupt videos when power loss during recording