# How to fix "moov atom not found" error in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

Well, I'm using [this](https://github.com/edmand46/webm_bot) project to create a Telegram bot which receives URL of `.mp4` files, downloads them on server and uploads them to Telegram.

#### Issue

Everything works fine so far, except converting certain `.mp4` files.

For example if I use a sample `.mp4` video from https://sample-videos.com/. Then it works fine and converts it successfully.

But if I use a video from some random website which is also simple `.mp4` file, it doesn't work and throws this error:

> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1932420] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1932420] moov atom not found
> data/720P_1500K_210306701.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: Share a failing mp4.

Comment: This may be a video that has not been fully uploaded (e.g. live stream). Hopefully *[How to add a MOOV atom in a mp4 video file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11551573/192373)* can help.

Comment: Give a try https://stackoverflow.com/a/44282151/6180077

Comment: In my case, I was trying to operate on a file with size zero. Make sure your file isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ffprobe on the video. If you are having issues with the probe too.. It could be that it is corrupted.

you can also try to do this before encoding

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy input_first_clean_pass.mp4
```

and then launch the command on input_first_clean_pass.mp4

Answer (score -2):

This really depends on the software that handles the upload.
The moov atom is either located at the beginning, or at the end of the file.
If the software only looks at the first part of the file, and the moov atom is at the end, it will not know how to deal with that file until the file upload is completed.

What you could do, prior to uploading, is move the moov file to the start of the video, it's more likely that the software only checks for the moov atom at the start of the file.
With ffmpeg, the command is:

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v copy -c:a copy -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

That would move it to the start of the file.
You will need to do this for every video though.