# Converting Video for Android using FFMPEG

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

What i am trying to do is convert video into mp4 format that will play in Android.

I've gone through http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

I am setting the following options

```
-vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ac 1 -ab 128k
```

yet I get the error message "Sorry, This Video is not valid for streaming to this device"

I Played the video in android browser using videoJS http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4 and it WORKS fine.

I download the video oceans-clip.mp4 and tried to convert using minimalist options

```
-y -i working.mp4 -vprofile baseline pleasework.mp4
```

yet I get the same error message.

The following is the FFMPEG info dump of the video files

**Working.mp4**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ffmpeg version N-40229-g24e3f44-syslint Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
    [1] =>   built on Apr 29 2012 22:01:41 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
    [2] =>   configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/cpffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-decoder=liba52 --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cpffmpeg/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib --enable-version3 --extra-version=syslint
    [3] =>   libavutil      51. 48.100 / 51. 48.100
    [4] =>   libavcodec     54. 17.101 / 54. 17.101
    [5] =>   libavformat    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
    [6] =>   libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
    [7] =>   libavfilter     2. 72.100 /  2. 72.100
    [8] =>   libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
    [9] =>   libswresample   0. 11.100 /  0. 11.100
    [10] =>   libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
    [11] => Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'working.mp4':
    [12] =>   Metadata:
    [13] =>     major_brand     : isom
    [14] =>     minor_version   : 1
    [15] =>     compatible_brands: isomavc1
    [16] =>     creation_time   : 2010-05-18 04:24:00
    [17] =>   Duration: 00:00:46.54, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3342 kb/s
    [18] =>     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x264 [SAR 132:133 DAR 320:133], 3195 kb/s, SAR 127:128 DAR 635:264, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    [19] =>     Metadata:
    [20] =>       creation_time   : 2010-05-18 04:24:00
    [21] =>       handler_name    : GPAC ISO Video Handler
    [22] =>     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 144 kb/s
    [23] =>     Metadata:
    [24] =>       creation_time   : 2010-05-18 04:24:01
    [25] =>       handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler
    [26] => At least one output file must be specified
)
```

**Not Working.mp4**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ffmpeg version N-40229-g24e3f44-syslint Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
    [1] =>   built on Apr 29 2012 22:01:41 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
    [2] =>   configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/cpffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-decoder=liba52 --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cpffmpeg/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib --enable-version3 --extra-version=syslint
    [3] =>   libavutil      51. 48.100 / 51. 48.100
    [4] =>   libavcodec     54. 17.101 / 54. 17.101
    [5] =>   libavformat    54.  3.100 / 54.  3.100
    [6] =>   libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
    [7] =>   libavfilter     2. 72.100 /  2. 72.100
    [8] =>   libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
    [9] =>   libswresample   0. 11.100 /  0. 11.100
    [10] =>   libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
    [11] => Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'pleasework.mp4':
    [12] =>   Metadata:
    [13] =>     major_brand     : isom
    [14] =>     minor_version   : 512
    [15] =>     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    [16] =>     creation_time   : 2010-05-18 04:24:00
    [17] =>     encoder         : Lavf54.3.100
    [18] =>   Duration: 00:00:46.54, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1843 kb/s
    [19] =>     Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x264 [SAR 127:128 DAR 635:264], 1715 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    [20] =>     Metadata:
    [21] =>       creation_time   : 2010-05-18 04:24:00
    [22] =>       handler_name    : VideoHandler
    [23] =>     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 124 kb/s
    [24] =>     Metadata:
    [25] =>       creation_time   : 2010-05-18 04:24:00
    [26] =>       handler_name    : SoundHandler
    [27] => At least one output file must be specified
)
```

The metadata looks almost the same yet it doesn't seem to play in android. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The MP4 created by ffmpeg has the moov header at the tail. That is why you are getting this error message. ffmpeg can put the moov header in front (suitable for streaming).

Simply run:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Also refer to [Post processing in ffmpeg to move 'moov atom' in MP4 files (qt-faststart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061798/post-processing-in-ffmpeg-to-move-moov-atom-in-mp4-files-qt-faststart)

Comment: Or use the `-movflags faststart` option in ffmpeg.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: Your comment worked for me but it made my video flicker when played full-screen on an Android tablet. It's fine everywhere else (iOS, Mac, PC).

Comment: @dashmug I don't have an andriod tablet to test with, but I doubt the issue is due to `-movflags faststart` option and I don't know your ffmpeg command and the complete console output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: It's working now. It's not due to the `-movflags faststart` option. I added `-vprofile baseline` and it's good. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

libfaac is not supported anymore, You can use this configuration:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -s 480x320 -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec aac -strict -2 -ac 1 -ar 16000 -r 13 -ab 32000 -aspect 3:2 <output>
```

Comment: @user1079877 Works Fine , Thanks

Comment: Video is compressed successfully. It is playing in android and iPhone but it is not playing in browser. Please help me.

Comment: This topic is about Android itself not browser. HTML5 has many implementation for different browers.

Comment: This will output MPEG-4 Part 2 video instead of H.264.

Comment: it worked. it's low res enough vlc can play it from the micro sd card on the phone

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was:

```
ffmpeg -i <INPUT_VIDEO> -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -c:a libvo_aacenc -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 128k -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: `-c:a libvo_aacenc` was deprecated, use `-c:a aac` instead

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input_file.mp4 -s 352x288 -b:v 384k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8 -subq 6 -trellis 0 -refs 5 -bf 0 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -c:a aac -ac 1 -ar 16000 -r 13 -ab 32000 -aspect 3:2 -strict experimental output_file.3gp
```

I converted to 3gp. It works in API 16 or higher, using VideoView.

Answer (score 1):

What I did here was to record a video with my Android device and see what it has configured with FFMPEG:

```
C:\Users\muradgui\Documents\SmartTrust\Software\ffmpeg-20170418-6108805-win64-static\bin>ffmpeg -i android.mp4
ffmpeg version N-85588-g6108805 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avis
e-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --e
m --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpe
-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enabl
 --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 61.100 / 55. 61.100
  libavcodec     57. 93.100 / 57. 93.100
  libavformat    57. 72.101 / 57. 72.101
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 84.101 /  6. 84.101
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
[h264 @ 00000000003184e0] no frame!
[aac @ 000000000050c900] Input buffer exhausted before END element found
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'android.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-03-08T17:30:26.000000Z
    com.android.version: 6.0.1
  Duration: 00:00:00.86, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2160 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280, 2107 kb/s, 31.72 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-08T17:30:26.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 56 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-08T17:30:26.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
At least one output file must be specified
```

I'm not very technical but this is what drew my attention mostly:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280, 2107 kb/s, 31.72 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
```

I used the following commands to successfully convert my video so that it can be played on my Android:

```
ffmpeg -i out.avi -vcodec h264 -s 720x1280 test3.mp4
```

I suspect my problem was that the resolution of my original video was too much for my device. This is what it was earlier:

```
C:\Users\muradgui\Documents\SmartTrust\Software\ffmpeg-20170418-6108805-win64-static\bin>ffmpeg -i out.avi
ffmpeg version N-85588-g6108805 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-zma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 61.100 / 55. 61.100
  libavcodec     57. 93.100 / 57. 93.100
  libavformat    57. 72.101 / 57. 72.101
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 84.101 /  6. 84.101
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
Input #0, avi, from 'out.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.72.101
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4788 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 2250x4000 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 4596 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
```

Which has a 2250x4000 resolution (it was an image from the same device I transformed into a video with this article https://superuser.com/questions/617392/ffmpeg-image-sequence-with-various-durations).

I tried simply resizing the image without changing the codec to h264 but that didn't yield very good image. h264 did it for me :)

Hope this helps!! <3