# How convert mp4(kazam) to mp4(android/iphone) ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, android-ffmpeg

## Hello team

I have a problem, i thougnt that all files mp4 were similar but when i try to open it in android or iphone, not all files can open. I use kazam to recorder screen and kazam save it in mp4. but this mp4 not is possible open in my browser, but i have reviewed all properties comparate to others videos that phones can plays and all are same.

## Properties files

[image]

### [this is the mp4 file for you try](https://fotogena.co/public/video.mp4)

So i have searched in internet how convert they to mp4 avaliable for android but i can't solve it

**command ffmpeg tryed**

```
ffmpeg -i ${data.file.path} -c:a aac -ac 2 -movflags +faststart ${newVideoPath}

ffmpeg -i ${data.file.path} -c:v libx264 -c:a libmp3lame -movflags +faststart ${newVideoPath}

ffmpeg -i ${data.file.path} -c:a libfdk_aac -movflags +faststart ${newVideoPath}
```

But nothing work, i have found question [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171826/converting-video-for-android-using-ffmpeg) but it didn't work me

Comment: The problem is the 4:4:4 which isn't playable in typical players. Add `-vf format=yuv420p` to convert it to the compatible 4:2:0.

Comment: hey it works, thanks!!