# M4a (mp4) audio file encoded with pydub+ffmpeg doesn't play on Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mp4, codec, pydub

I have a python script to split up some `wav` files and export to `m4a` using [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub).  I'm able to get these files to play on several devices, but not on an Android device (using Google Pixel 3).  When I try encoding with straight `ffmpeg` in terminal, that works fine on the Android device.

What is the difference in these two files, and since `pydub` is using `ffmpeg`, what do I need to change to make it do exactly the same as the `ffmpeg` command?

**Not working**

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
>>> audio = AudioSegment.from_wav("input.wav")
>>> slice = audio[1000:3000]
>>> slice.export("pydub_export.m4a", format="mp4", parameters=["-ac", "1", "-c:a", "libfdk_aac", "-profile:a", "aac_he", "-vbr", "2"])
```

`mediainfo` output:

```
General
Complete name                            : pydub_export.m4a
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/mp41)
File size                                : 11.7 KiB
Duration                                 : 2 s 115 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 45.1 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.29.100

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AAC LC SBR
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity with Spectral Band Replication
Commercial name                          : HE-AAC
Format settings                          : NBC
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-5
Duration                                 : 2 s 115 ms
Duration_LastFrame                       : -22 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 41.4 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel layout                           : C
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 21.533 FPS (2048 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 10.7 KiB (92%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
```

**Working**

```
$ffmpeg -i input.wav -acodec copy -ss 1 -to 3 input_slice.wav
$ffmpeg -i input_slice.wav -ac 1 -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -vbr 2 ffmpeg_export.m4a
```

`mediainfo` output:

```
General
Complete name                            : ffmpeg_export.m4a
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Apple audio with iTunes info
Codec ID                                 : M4A  (isom/iso2)
File size                                : 11.2 KiB
Duration                                 : 2 s 112 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 43.6 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.29.100

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AAC LC SBR
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity with Spectral Band Replication
Commercial name                          : HE-AAC
Format settings                          : NBC
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-5
Duration                                 : 2 s 112 ms
Duration_LastFrame                       : -25 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 39.9 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel layout                           : C
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 21.533 FPS (2048 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 10.3 KiB (91%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
```

I already tried [moving metadata to the front](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14172629/129486) with `-movflags faststart` on the broken file and it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [pydub's logging](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#debugging), I was able to see exactly the `ffmpeg` command it produced.

Turns out that the `format=...` argument in `pydub` provides the flag `-f ...` to `ffmpeg`.  It was just a matter of finding the right `-f` argument to use, and `mp4` was giving me the bad file.

[@Gyan 's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62725673/129486) suggested `-f ipod`. So using `format="ipod"` in `pydub` gives the correct output.