# ffmpeg - what is the default format for .m4a output?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, aac, m4a

I have two commands, one in which I specify the output format as `-f mp4`:

`ffmpeg -i input.wav -ac 1 -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -vbr 2 -f mp4 test_export_1.m4a`

And one which lets ffmpeg guess based on the extension:

`ffmpeg -i input.wav -ac 1 -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -vbr 2 test_export_2.m4a`

This gives me two different results.

The first one:

```
$ffprobe test_export_1.m4a
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test_export_1.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:07.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 40 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 39 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

The second one:

```
$ffprobe test_export_2.m4a
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test_export_2.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4A 
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:07.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 40 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 39 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

The first one with the brand `isom` won't play on Android devices.  The second one works fine.  Why are these outputs different, and how can I specify the correct format to get `major_brand : M4A`  like the second one?  I'm using `pydub` to run the commands, which requires a format flag.

Comment: see "movflags fastart"  here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171826/converting-video-for-android-using-ffmpeg  that may help

Comment: @RobertRowntree I did try that but it still didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.m4a` is not a recommended ISO extension but is typically used by Apple. It has a limited list of acceptable codecs as compared to `.mp4`. Format flag is `-f ipod`.

Comment: Thanks! The audio is embedded in a mobile app so for my purpose I think it's easier to use `.m4a`