# Flash playback slow with progressive download

Tags: video.js

Using VideoJS 4.0.4 (it also did this in version 3) the playback is slow/choppy in Chrome (not tested in other browsers) when using the Flash player. The playback smooths out after the buffer finishes loading the full video. Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. It ended up being the Flash player. I went to `chrome://plugins`, clicked the `+` at the top right, and noticed I had 2 Flash plugins installed: `11.7.700.225` (pepflashplayer.dll) and `11.7.700.224` (NPSWF32_11_7_700_224.dll). I disabled them one at a time and retried the video - the `11.7.700.224` one ran flawlessly while buffering, while the `11.7.700.225` version was the one causing the choppiness.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are experiencing so apologies if this is irrelevant, but for me the flash player was waiting until the whole video was loaded before it would start playing.

If you are using the mp4 format, I found that moving the moov atom to the front of the movie file with qt-faststart helped a lot.

Here are some resources I found when I had this similar problem.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html

http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/1141-ie8-flash-fallback-buffers-entire-video-before-it-starts-to-play

[Post processing in ffmpeg to move 'moov atom' in MP4 files (qt-faststart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061798/post-processing-in-ffmpeg-to-move-moov-atom-in-mp4-files-qt-faststart)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That didn't end up being the issue (all are fast start enabled) - it ended up being the Flash player. I went to `chrome://plugins`, clicked the `+` at the top right, and noticed I had 2 Flash plugins installed: `11.7.700.225` (pepflashplayer.dll) and `11.7.700.224` (NPSWF32_11_7_700_224.dll). I disabled them one at a time and retried the video - the `11.7.700.224` one ran flawlessly while buffering, while the `11.7.700.225` version was the one causing the choppiness.