# How to enable video seekable in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web video player with HTML5 for the video player, it's not seekable, is there any way to enable this feature, my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var video;
    var playlist;
    var tracks;
    var current;

    $(document).ready(function() {
     init();
    });
    function init(){
       current = 0;
       video = $("video");
       playlist = $("#playlist");
       tracks = playlist.find("li a");
       len = tracks.length - 1;
       video[0].volume = .50;
       video[0].play();
       playlist.find("a").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           link = $(this);
           current = link.parent().index();
           run(link, video[0]);
       });
       video[0].addEventListener("ended",function(e){
           current++;
           if(current == len){
               current = 0;
               link = playlist.find("a")[0];
           }else{
               link = playlist.find("a")[current];    
           }
           run($(link),video[0]);
       });
    }
    function run(link, player){
           player.src = link.attr("href");
           par = link.parent();
           par.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
           video[0].load();
           video[0].play();
    }

    </script>
```

I have tried adding:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.currentTime = 18;
```

after the video tag but it doesn't work, did I implement it wrong?

Comment: Is your movie faststart enabled? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061798/post-processing-in-ffmpeg-to-move-moov-atom-in-mp4-files-qt-faststart

Comment: I typed in `-movflags faststart` in my terminal but it seems that my openwrt doesn't support that command