# How to update MP4 with the video length

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, youtube-dl

I used youtube-dl to obtain a friends video. When I play it in VLC, I notice there is no time/length shown. As we need to cut part of this video with ffmpeg, can I use ffmpeg (or similar tool) to determine the length of the video, and then update the MP4 to contain the time/length ?

Comment: with a cli/term session you can 'ffmpeg -i $my.mp4' and the stdout will show various streams/tracks and the duration of each.   thats not automated solution . may be other probes / parsers that have better api for gets on that metadata than ffmpeg.  not sure

Comment: Thanks Robert. That worked fine and I may only need Konsole to do it, as the previous mp4 file had the time/length in it (used youtube-dl to obtain it from periscope). Here is the part of the output ..
  Duration: 00:09:03.12, start: 24.154000, bitrate: 317 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x102]: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
    Stream #0:1[0x100]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 320x568, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 93 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified

Comment: When I used ffmpeg to cut part of the mp4, without knowing the total length, the output didn't have any length/time. Now that I know the duration, and tried ffmpeg again, the output file contains the duration. Here is what I used  `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -i VideoClip2.mp4 -t 00:08:58 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc VideoClip2.new.mp4`

Comment: Okay, so the duration has been added into the destination MP4. Still need to know how to write the duration into the source MP4 file. No doubt the duration is in a header/s.

Comment: Output will have time if you "move the atom" to the head of the file. ---flag is the name of the declarative for move atom

Comment: Looked at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html , and the only reference to atom was `-cpuflags flags (global)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061798/post-processing-in-ffmpeg-to-move-moov-atom-in-mp4-files-qt-faststart.  -movflags faststart

Comment: @oygle Try to simply remux it `fmpeg -i source.mp4 -c copy output.mp4`. `faststart` is only useful for progressive download.

Comment: @aergistal - Tried that command, got errrors - `[mp4 @ 0x1ecace0] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x1ecace0] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers` and the conversion failed

Comment: Have simply used the `-i` parameter to get the duration. Then used that value to create an MP4 of _that_ length (duration). Then play it and determine where the start/stop should be.  Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @oygle add `-flags +global_header` for the last error.