# What is the difference between these 2 videos?

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg, mediainfo

I am using [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg) to resize a video.

I can't figure out what's happening though. I have 2 video files, one works but the other doesn't. I've been scouring the `mediainfo` outputs of both files, checking for discrepancies but other than `filesize`, `duration` etc. there's no difference (same `codec`, `format`, `width`/`height`, `frame rate` etc)

[Here's](https://github.com/98mprice/videos) a link to both files.

I've been reading these video files into fluent-ffmpeg using an input stream, as so:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ffmpeg(file.stream)
      .output(path)
      .size('426x240')
      .on('start', function() {
          console.log('started');
      })
      .on('error', function(err) {
          console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
      })
      .on('progress', function(progress) {
          console.log('... frames: ' + progress.frames);
      })
      .on('end', function() {
        console.log('Finished processing');
        resolve();
      })
      .run();
});
```

The working file prints:

```
started
... frames: 86
... frames: 107
Finished processing
```

But the non-working file doesn't seem to have any frames, and prints:

```
started
... frames: 0
Finished processing
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

The ffmpeg command being executed:

```
ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -y -filter:v scale=w=426:h=240 uploads/works.mp4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've been scouring the mediainfo outputs of both files, checking for discrepancies but other than filesize, duration etc. there's no difference

It does, but in full mode only. try `mediainfo -f` on the files, you'll see:

```
IsStreamable                             : Yes
```

for the working file, and

```
IsStreamable                             : No
```

For the non working file.

a "no" here means that the input needs to support seek (header is at the end, player needs to seek to end for parsing header then seek back to beginning for parsing data).

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. I was able to get it working by moving the header to the front of the file, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422258/ffmpeg-move-the-header-to-the-front-of-the-file)

Comment: Is it possible to get isStreamable in ffprobe?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like ffmpeg have problem probing the file when you pass it as a stream. But it does work if you pass it as a file. Could be because probing/demuxer can optionally use seeks etc. I tried to increase the probe buffer but didn't get it to work.

This do not work:

```
cat doesnt_work.mp4 | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 test.mp4
```

But this works:

```
ffmpeg -i doesnt_work.mp4 test.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll save it to a temporary file on disk and resize from there.